# Sqlite query syntax error

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to update **budget** column in **movieDataset** table using **info_type_id and movie_info columns** from movie_info table. The below is the query:

```
UPDATE movieDataset
SET budget=REPLACE(movie_info.info,',','')
WHERE movieDataset.movie_id IN (
SELECT movie_info.movie_id
FROM movie_info
WHERE movie_info.info_type_id=105
)
```

Data:
The corresponding info for info_type_id 105 is $40,000/$17,000 etc.

Desired output:

budget column should have, $40000/$17000 etc

I'm using sqlite3 and DB Browser to execute the query

Error message:

No such column:movie_info.info

Tables relationship:

They have the same movie.id

Tables defintion:

movieDataset(movie.id, budget)

movie_info(movie.id, info, movie_info_id)

Thank you

Comment: Show the actual error message, and the table definition, and how they are related.

Comment: Thanks CL for your help. I have edited my question to include your above request.

Comment: Are you sure you can use '.' in a column name?  I thought the rules only allowed for alphanumeric and underscores.

Comment: Yes we can. As stated in the Replace function definition "replace( string, from_substring, to_substring )"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the outer query, the `movie_info` table is not visible. To get values from that table, you have to query them with a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
UPDATE movieDataset
SET budget = replace((SELECT info
                      FROM movie_info
                      WHERE movie_id = movieDataset.movie_id
                        AND info_type_id = 105
                     ), ',', '')
WHERE movie_id IN (
    SELECT movie_id
    FROM movie_info
    WHERE info_type_id = 105
);
```